# Custom source, res and AndroidManifest location in Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project in Eclipse, stored in my default workspace. But I want to have the Java sources, the `res` directory and the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to be in another (shared) directory, without moving the whole project to that location.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add an aditional sources folder. It can be done as follows:

- Right-click on the project.
- Click **Properties**.
- In the properties window, click **Java Build Path**.
- Select the tab **Source** (it probably is already selected).
- Click on the button **Link Source**.

Now you can specify an additional sources folder.

However, it is not (yet) possible to select a custom location of the AndroidManifest.xml file or the resources folder.

A workaround to achieve this, is to create symbolic links.

1. Go to the Eclipse project directory.
2. Delete the `src` folder (copy the contents to your custom location).
3. Create a symbolic link, named `src`, to your custom location.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the `res` and possibly the `assets` directory, and the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

You can read [more information about symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or [NTFS symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)) and how to create them.

Comment: why you cant write a page on this, ?

Comment: @Sreekanthss What do you mean?

Comment: i mean some blog about your question and answer

Comment: When people have questions about programming, they often go to Stackoverflow and search for it. People will find this much easier than some blog on some website.
It is also [encouraged to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: A year later it seems like it is still not possible to select a custom location of the AndroidManifest.xml file or the resources folder.

Comment: Why does Maven want to have the manifest file into src/main/ and Eclipse in the app root folder ? Can't these two agree on something ?

Comment: @StephaneEybert I don't know. But I agree with Eclipse, since the `src` directory should only contain `*.java` files.